# Azure Devops pipelines - clone multiple repos by same tag or branch

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-repos

I have three Azure Repos, all in the same ADO Project - repo-0001, repo-0002, repo-0003

repo-0001 has my yaml pipeline which has a manual trigger, and the pipeline needs to be run on demand by either branch or tag (eg `release/branch001`, `release/tag001`)

The Pipeline checkouts out repo-0001, repo-0002 & repo-0003 at whatever ref (branch or tag) is used to start the pipeline in repo-0001 (these branches & tags are created by a different process and are always present in all repos)

I've been using `$(Build.SourceBranch)` to extract:

branch - `refs/heads/release/branch001`

tag - `refs/tags/release/tag001`

This yaml works for a pipeline started using a **branch**, but not for a **tag**, and it results in `Could not get the latest source version for repository repo-0001 hosted on Azure Repos using refs/heads/refs/tags/release/tag001` so it appears to append the whole ref path of the tag to `refs/heads`

```
variables:
  REPOSITORY_SOURCE_BRANCH: $(Build.SourceBranch)

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: repo-0001
      type: git
      name: aks/repo-0001
      ref: $(REPOSITORY_SOURCE_BRANCH)
    - repository: repo-0002
      type: git
      name: aks/repo-0002
      ref: $(REPOSITORY_SOURCE_BRANCH)
    - repository: repo-0003
      type: git
      name: aks/repo-0003
      ref: $(REPOSITORY_SOURCE_BRANCH)
```

I can make it work with a tag by doing something like this, or passing in as a parameter

```
variables:
  tag: "release/tag001"

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: repo-0001
      type: git
      name: aks/repo-0001
      ref: 'refs/tags/$(tag)'

etc
```

But that's not what I need...

Can a tag ref be passed in from pipeline variables to make this work, and is there a way to make it flexible so that I can use the same pipeline code for tags and branches?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ref field in repositories Resources doesn't support defining Pipeline variable. It only supports hardcode the ref value.

> Can a tag ref be passed in from pipeline variables to make this work, and is there a way to make it flexible so that I can use the same pipeline code for tags and branches?

To meet your requirement, you can change to use the following format to checkout the repo.

```
- checkout: git://MyProject/MyRepo@refs/tags/$(tag)
- checkout: git://MyProject/MyRepo@$(REPOSITORY_SOURCE_BRANCH)
```

Here is an example:

```
variables:
  REPOSITORY_SOURCE_BRANCH: test
steps:
- checkout: git://aks/repo-0001@$(REPOSITORY_SOURCE_BRANCH)
```

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [Checking out a specific ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#checking-out-a-specific-ref)